# Is Cricket the only sport which is played at a county level?

Tags: cricket

So, most sports have local amateur teams.

Most sports have a professional team or two for each town or city.

Most sports have teams who represent their nation.

The only one I know of tho have county (regional) teams is Cricket.

Is it the only one? And if so, why this distinction?

Comment: I think there are a lot of regional teams, i.e football: in the eredivisie you have fc Twente, which is a small region in Gelderland. Also in the NCAA you have the Tar Heels who represent the university of North Carolina. That's a whole state

Comment: Isn't that just a university?

Comment: It is, but don't they represent the state of North Carolina instead of Chapel Hill?

Comment: @KevinTinnemans No, it is the state (i.e. publicly funded) university which happens to be in North Carolina rather than an official representative of the state.

Comment: "County" is very country specific... in NZ specifically we have provinces, which various sport competitions have. Funny enough cricket is more regional where the traditional provencies are combined to make a regional cricket team. But I think this is based on sustainability

Comment: If you consider English counties, then just about every sport I can think of is played between county teams at the amateur level.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of rubgy competitions which are county based, or close to:

- English rugby union has a [county championship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/County_Championship_(rugby_union)), although it is at a lower level than the professional game which is traditionally club based.
- Australian rugby league has the [State of Origin series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Origin_series), where players from New South Wales and Queensland compete against each other. While this is secondary to the main NRL competition, it is still a significant honour to be selected for the series. English rugby league used to have the [War of the Roses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_League_War_of_the_Roses) between Yorkshire and Lancashire, but that is both discontinued and was never as prestigious as the State of Origin series.

Answer (score 2):

Gaelic sports such as Gaelic football and hurling are played at the county level with the All Ireland championships having a team from each of the counties. London and New York also field teams.

Within Ireland, the traditional Irish counties are used. Outside Ireland, the GAA (Gaelic Athletic Association) makes up its own “counties” which may or may not correspond to local counties or other jurisdictions.

Comment: With the complication that Kilkenny doesn't play football.

Answer (score 0):

Many other sports in the United Kingdom have competitions with teams representing their county, for example [badminton](https://www.badmintonengland.co.uk/landingpage.asp?section=5825) and [tennis](https://www.lta.org.uk/competitions/team-competition/aegon-county-cup/aegon-county-cup-adult-events/).